# Understanding the difference between infinitely often and limit inferior

Tags: probability-theory

Consider the problem statement presented here: [Tail algebra and tail events in a sequence of i.i.d. random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2268255/tail-algebra-and-tail-events-in-a-sequence-of-i-i-d-random-variables).

> Suppose $\{X_1,X_2,\dots\}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables and
>
> $P[X_i=1]=P[X_i=-1]=\frac{1}{2}$
>
> Define $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Let $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \sigma\{X_k:k\geq n\} $ be the tail $\sigma-$algebra of $\{X_k\: k \geq 1\}$.
>
> Show that $B_{-}=\{\liminf_{n\to \infty} S_n=-\infty\}$ and $B_{+}=\{\limsup_{n\to \infty} S_n = \infty\}$ are tail events. Moreover $P(B_{-})=P(B_{+})$.

In the commends @Did states that "[...] *no*, since, in general $\{\lim\inf_{n\to\infty} S_n = -\infty\}\neq \{X_i = -1 \text{ infinitely often}\}$". What I can't understand is that why are the two sets different. Surely if $X_i$'s obtain the value of $-1$ infinitely often, then the limit of the partial averages tend to $-\infty$. Moreover, if the limit inferior of the partial averages tend to $-\infty$, then why don't $X_i$s obtain $-1 infinitely often?

Comment: Consider a sequence of realization $1,-1,1,-1,1,\ldots$, where $-1$ occurs infinitely often, but the partial sum is always nonnegative.

Comment: @Q9y5 Ah, now I see. Thanks! So it follows that $\{\lim\inf_{n\to\infty}S_n = -\infty\}\subset \{X_i = -1 \text{ infinitely often}\}$?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, this direction still holds.